# Any other methods for evaluating $\int\limits \frac{ x^2+x+1 }{ \sqrt{x^2-x+1} } dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried below and its getting tedious :

\begin{align}
& \int\frac{ x^2+x+1 }{ \sqrt{x^2-x+1} } dx \\= & \int\limits \frac{(2x-1)+ x^2-x+2 }{ \sqrt{x^2-x+1} } dx \\=  &\int\limits \frac{(2x-1)dx}{ \sqrt{x^2-x+1} }  +   \int\frac{ (x^2-x+1 )dx}{ \sqrt{x^2-x+1} }  +   \int\frac{ dx }{ \sqrt{x^2-x+1} }  \\ 
=&\cdots\\
\end{align}

wolfram shows a very much simplified answer :
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+%28x%5E2%2Bx%2B1%29%2F%28sqrt%28x%5E2-x%2B1%29%29

I'm wondering if there is a nice way to work this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\int\limits \frac{ x^2+x+1 }{ \sqrt{x^2-x+1} } dx = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\int \frac{x^2+x+1 }{\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + 1} }
$$
set $t= \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)$
we obtain
$$
\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{3t^2+4\sqrt{3}t + 7}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}
$$
This is the same way as yours but a little cleaner to solve :).

Comment: Wow! this looks really neat xD next $t = \tan \theta $ and  seems it simplifies nicely... I'll try.. thanks a lot !

Comment: No worries. Go for it and good luck :). Like I said it's not a drastically different approach, it's just setting up the environment to solve the integral.

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding a separate answer as it is markedly different from my other answer.

In fact, your way is not too tough either

$$\int\limits \frac{ x^2+x+1 }{ \sqrt{x^2-x+1} } dx =\cdots=  \int\limits \frac{(2x-1)dx}{ \sqrt{x^2-x+1} }  +   \int\limits \sqrt{x^2-x+1}\ dx   +   \int\limits \frac{ dx }{ \sqrt{x^2-x+1} } $$

For the first integral, observe that $\displaystyle\frac{d(x^2-x+1)}{dx}=2x-1$

for the rest two as $\displaystyle x^2-x+1=\frac{(2x-1)^2+(\sqrt3)^2}4,$ set $2x-1=y$

and utilize $\#1,\#8$ of [this](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ11/integ11.html)

Comment: I'm always looking for efficient methods for integrating ^_^ Got this completely! thanks so much :D

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

I think using [Trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution) of 
$\displaystyle x^2-x+1=\frac{(2x-1)^2+(\sqrt3)^2}4$

with $2x-1=\sqrt3\tan\theta$ won't be a bad way to start with

Answer (score 2):

Regroup the numerator into three terms below $$x^2+x+1= \frac74+ 2(x-\frac12)+ (x-\frac12)^2$$
and integrate accordingly
$$I = \int\frac{ x^2+x+1 }{ \sqrt{x^2-x+1} } dx =\frac74  I_1+2I_2+I_3$$
where the three resulting integrals are respectively
\begin{align}
&I_1= \int\frac{1 }{ \sqrt{x^2-x+1} } dx
= \sinh^{-1}\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt3}\\
 &I_2=\int\frac{ x-\frac12}{ \sqrt{x^2-x+1} } dx 
= \sqrt{x^2-x+1}\\
&I_3=\int\frac{ (x-\frac12)^2 }{ \sqrt{x^2-x+1} } dx 
\overset{ibp} =\frac12 (x-\frac12)\sqrt{x^2-x+1}-\frac38I_1 \end{align}
Substitute above results into $I$ to obtain
$$I= (\frac x2+\frac74)\sqrt{x^2-x+1} +\frac{11}8\sinh^{-1}\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt3}
$$